# How can I include an image in a post?

Tags: support, images

If I want to use a picture to illustrate a question or an answer, how do I do that?

Do I need link to the picture hosted somewhere online or can I use also a picture which I have locally stored on my computer?

Can any user add a picture, or is it possible only from some reputation threshold?

Comment: I have added this question to this post: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/611/helping-our-new-users-transition-to-sports-se?cb=1. In addition to including an image, I would think it would be appropriate to provide a style guide (ie, when it is helpful to include images) to add some depth to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How can I include an image into a post !

Adding a picture to a question or answer is very easy , Just follow the steps.

1. Clicking the Insert Image button on the toolbar.
   [image: Add Image]
2. Then a popup should come , from that popup select an image from your computer, or the web.
   [image: Add Picture popup]
3. And click on add picture.
   [image: Added picture]
4. Then something like this will be generated in the text area
   `[![Image Description][1]][1]` , now you can add/edit your image's
   description.

**More Reference**

1.go through this [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498) post.

2.An animated image showing how to edit and add an image to a post.
[image: Animated.]

Comment: Your English is fine here :)

Comment: Still I am not sure. :)