# Is Quidditch considered on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is [Quidditch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quidditch) considered a sport? Are questions about Quidditch permitted here? Although some countries have established [rules](https://www.usquidditch.org/about/rules) for Quidditch games, I am unsure whether or not it would be considered a sport on Sports SE?

Answer (score 8):

There's obviously a line somewhere at which a sport is so niche that questions on it are going to be of no value to the community (e.g. "this game I made up yesterday"), but Quidditch has (in my never humble opinion) enough of a following and players that it's on-topic here. *Personally*, I think it's a bit silly, but that's neither here nor there.

For avoidance of doubt, I'd very strongly say only questions about the "real world" Quidditch (as you've linked to above) are on-topic. Any questions about the "Potterverse" Quidditch (with people flying around on brooms, etc) are off-topic here; they may be on-topic at [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quidditch).

Comment: In fact, Science Fiction and Fantasy does allow questions on the Potterverse Quidditch. I can see several well-received questions about various aspects of the in-universe game and possible rules scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

We've had 5 questions with the [quidditch](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quidditch) tag, none of which are closed (or have net negative votes), which says the community hasn't viewed these questions unfavorably.

We typically take newly-explored questions on a case-by-case basis. This is found in our [meta post for new users](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/612).