# Could we add autograph identification on What topics can I ask about here?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I came across this useful [*"Identify-This-X Questions"*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section on Movies & TV Stack Exchange help center. Since we have similar [autograph-identification](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autograph-identification) questions we could probably add something like that to our site's help center as well.

We are constantly getting questions about autograph identification with very low details. By forwarding the authors of those questions to that section of our help center, we could encourage the users to improve their questions. Those questions that will be improved within short amount of time may stay open, and others will get closed like they are being now most of the time.

Comment: How can we denote that this question is obsolete since `autograph-identification` questions are off-topic?

Comment: @Philip Kendall Sir, should I edit the question to indicate this question is obsolete, or something else could be done instead?

Comment: Superseded by https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/926/9502 et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy edited from [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)

Proposed:

### **Autograph Identification Questions**

Questions about autographs on sport memorabilia and equipment are on-topic for this site. These identification questions must be as descriptive as possible and should not consist of only an image for detail. Important details to include are:

1. Where and how you obtained it
2. An estimate of its age
3. Any known details of its origin
4. Any distinctive details on the item

Give the question a meaningful title that includes key identifying details. Avoid generic titles like "need help", "autograph identification".

Questions lacking in research or detail may get closed.

Comment: I've just put this content into the [autograph-identification tag wiki](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/autograph-identification/info) which seems a good home to it for me; we could then add a pointer to that information from the on-topic page if people think that's a good idea?