# Can we add "autograph identification" to the "Some kinds of questions should NOT be asked here" list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, on-topic

Currently, the "What topics can I ask about here?" [page](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes a list in which "Some kinds of questions should NOT be asked here." This list includes:

- Who is the better [team/athlete/etc.]?
- Who will win the [event/award/etc.]?
- Requests for sources/research
- Fantasy Sports
- Recreation, Fitness, or Outdoor activities
- Medical/Legal advice
- What is or is not a sport

Due to the perpetual influx of autograph-identification questions, and a [growing list](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/918/can-we-have-a-warning-to-posters-when-about-to-publish-an-autograph-or-signature) of favorable yet unexecuted ideas, I thought this request is appropriate and easy to execute, in theory.

Can we add "autograph identification" to the "Some kinds of questions should NOT be asked here" list?

<sub>Note: Do not confuse this request with this related but obsolete request: [Could we add autograph identification on What topics can I ask about here?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/830/could-we-add-autograph-identification-on-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here)</sub>

Comment: Perhaps a more related meta discussion to strengthen this request: [Revisiting autograph identification questions (conclusion: off-topic)](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/846/revisiting-autograph-identification-questions-conclusion-off-topic)

Comment: @AndrewT. Perhaps I am being myopic, but the past two months of meta activity on this site has suggested a very strong interest in deterring autograph identification questions, to go so far as to duplicate a previously made request. ([1](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/915)) ([2](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/916)) ([3](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/918)) In other words, I'm not sure the strength of this request is a concern.

Comment: @AndrewT. Another [question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/how-can-we-reduce-the-number-of-autograph-identification-questions-asked-by-new) has come in, duplicating at least two previous questions on the topic.