# Where can I ask about autograph identification?

Tags: discussion

In 2018 after [a discussion on meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/846/revisiting-autograph-identification-questions-conclusion-off-topic) it was decided that autograph identification questions are no longer considered on-topic on Sports Stack Exchange. Since then, such question are typically closed relatively quickly.

Still, it would be more friendly to the users asking these questions if they were presented with some possible alternatives where to ask such question. If we are able to find some recommendations and collect them here on meta, we could link in a comment to this question.

**Question.** Can you recommend some sites which are useful for users looking for autograph identifications?

For users asking about autograph identification, this would make their first interaction with this site a bit more pleasant (despite the fact that the question was closed). Which is a good thing - this would improve the image of the site a bit and also increase the likelihood that the user returns to the site and possibly contributes to some areas which are on topic.

Comment: I understand that this might be considered off-topic here on meta. However, having such resource  *somewhere* on the site might be useful and meta seems the only reasonable place for this.

Comment: While I think this is a good question, I found a lot of results with "autograph identification", though I don't know which ones are reliable, active... It's also interesting to see that we are still on top results with old questions that have a lot of votes. We can't really blame users to try to ask here.

Comment: There are precedents on other SE sites for a Community Wiki meta question listing resources for questions that would be off-topic on the site itself.  A CW answer to this question may well be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I know of a couple of options for users that need autograph identification help:

- Facebook group [Identify Your Autographs](https://www.facebook.com/IdentifyYourAutographs/)
- Subreddit [r/AutographAssistance](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutographAssistance/)

I would like to take this opportunity, once again, to point to [my answer](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/927/1723) that suggests a course of action that I believe would stop the flood of autograph identification questions here.

Comment: You say this, but where are your delete votes to make it happen?

Comment: @Nij Are there any active moderators left on this site that can make this happen all at once?

Comment: @Nij I have just issued 10 delete votes and hit my daily limit. This is really a job for a moderator.

Comment: I believe a moderator could do it in one go (unsure of whether they have unlimited deletes, reasonably sure they have a batch process as well). But since there are several other issues going unresolved, I would say they're on holiday at best.

Comment: @Nij seeing the activity in the queues and other actions it's safe to assume that we have no active moderators left. Holidays don't last that long. I've reached out to SE and they're already aware of the situation. I guess we'll face an election sometime soon when they have the time to initiate one. And no, mods do not have those limits (or at least not that low).

Comment: @Nij It took a few days, but I believe that I have now issued a delete vote on every [question tagged autograph-identification](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autograph-identification).

Comment: The tag (autograph-identification) [has been removed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/conversation/removal-of-the-autograph-identification-tag).